# UICollectionView created in .xib is nil Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

The collectionView always is nil, I created it in .xib.
Crash occurs in the first interaction with the collectionView
Thank you in advance.

This is the error. 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
class ChannelsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate  {

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate().managedObjectContext;

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self

        self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName:"ChannelsCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the UICollectionView has a reference outlet to the collectionView property within your xib?

Comment: At any point do you remove the collectionview from its superview?

Comment: @Acey No, I dont, Now I only have the collectionView with datasource methods.

Comment: @user3092406 hey, I faced the same problem! Do you solve it? 
can you please tell me how u did it ? 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that I was not loading the nib. Try this.

```
init() {
    super.init(nibName: "ChannelsViewController", bundle: nil)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
} 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self

    self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName:"ChannelsCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}
```